# How to use str.contains() in a conditional statement to apply a function to some elements of a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, urlparse

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that holds various URLs to websites:

```
df:
    ID   URL
0   1    https://www.Facebook.com/fr
1   2    https://Twitter.com/de
2   3    https://www.Youtube.com
3   4    www.Microsoft.com
4   5    https://www.Stackovervlow.com
```

I am using `urlparse().netloc` to clean the URLs to only have the domain names (e.g., from https://www.Facebook.com/fr to [www.Facebook.com](http://www.Facebook.com)). Some of the URLs are already in a clean format ([www.Microsoft.com](http://www.Microsoft.com) above), and applying `urlparse().netloc` to these clean URLs results in an empty cell. Therefore, I am trying to apply the `urlparse().netloc` function to elements of the URL column where the element contains the string 'http', else it should return the original URL. Here is the code I have be trying to use:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].apply(
    lambda x: urlparse(x).netloc if x.str.contains("http", na=False) else x
)
```

However, I get this error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`. Any help on how I can overcome this to complete the task would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) therefore your function (lambda) receives element (`str`) itself, so you might simply us `in` as follows

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].apply(
    lambda x: urlparse(x).netloc if "http" in x else x
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is already a string not the `Series`. So use `x.find`:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].apply(
    lambda x: urlparse(x).netloc if x.find("http") != -1 else x
)
print(df)

# Output:
   ID                    URL
0   1       www.Facebook.com
1   2            Twitter.com
2   3        www.Youtube.com
3   4      www.Microsoft.com
4   5  www.Stackovervlow.com
```

But you can use `str.extract` to get netloc:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.extract(r'(?:^https?://)?([^/]+)', expand=False)
print(df)

# Output:
   ID                    URL
0   1       www.Facebook.com
1   2            Twitter.com
2   3        www.Youtube.com
3   4      www.Microsoft.com
4   5  www.Stackovervlow.com
```